# TERADATA GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION; MESSAGE_TEXT is null

Tags: teradata

why is the value of MESSAGE_TEXT null?
Other variables are set.

```
BEGIN -- Continue Handler
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42000'
   BEGIN -- Continue Handling
    SET vErrHandler = 'CONTINUE';
    GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1 vLogMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    
    CALL SP_DEBUG(cProcedureName, cInstanceIdentifier, 'vLogMessage',vLogMessage,cDebugIndicator);
   
   END; -- Continue Handling
   
   DROP TABLE #CALENDAR_MONTH;
   DROP TABLE #MONTH_LIST;
  END; -- Continue Handler
```

Comment: Because the (successful) SET statement clears the diagnostic area.

Comment: Doesn't work either